# What is the raw data color format after android hardware decoding?

Tags: android, video, colors, hardware-acceleration, stagefright

Are there a constant color format for hardware decoding or each different android device has its own color format?

I want to get the raw data which result from hardware decoding and render it myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Different android device has different color format after hardware decoding. It is complicated to separate hardware decoding and rendering. So it's a good idea that put these two steps together. Thus you need not to care about the color format.

Answer (score 0):

In case of different `android` devices, every vendor usually implements one of the standard `color formats` or a `SoC` specific format which will be well-tuned with the rest of the processing pipeline.

From `JellyBean`, `android` exposes a new class of objects called `MediaCodec` which provides the flexibility to a developer to create an instance of a `codec` as a standalone component. For your requirement, I feel `MediaCodec` is a right candidate. Some useful references are captured below that could help you achieve your objective.

1. [Creation of `MediaCodec`](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#318)
2. [Providing a `surface` to the underlying codec for `buffer` allocation](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#325)
3. [Queueing an input buffer](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#426)
4. [Retrieving an available output buffer](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#441)
   Here the output buffer is pushed into a queue as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#452)
5. [Rendering of the available output buffer after `A/V sync`](http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/av/cmds/stagefright/SimplePlayer.cpp#545)

If you wish to introduce any specific processing on the output of a video decoder, you could do so between steps 4 and 5 above or handle it as part of the `SurfaceTexture` / `Surface` which is given to the `decoder`. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the buffer-to-buffer tests in the [CTS EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest) source.  It demonstrates how to access the various known decoder formats.

Note there are "unknown" decoder formats; in particular, a number of popular devices will decode to an unpublished tiled format (which the CTS test currently gives a free pass to).

It's usually easier (and certainly much faster) to decode to a Surface and render that.